# How to pass parameter value for get , post and put method in OSB 12 c

Tags: osb

I need pass parameter like below

Http://host:port/wsintegration/id

Here I need to pass if value .

Please any one help how to do this .... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned if you're using the Http Transport of REST adapter.
Assuming you're using the HTTP transport you can insert the relative URI parameter to replace the 'id'.

```
<http:relative-URI>{fn:replace('/wsintegration/id','id','YOUR_VALUE')}</http:relative-URI>
```

[image]